# Subversion Client for AIX

Tags: aix, subversion

I am looking for `Subversion Client` that I can install on `AIX 7.1 TL 3`. All I need is just a light weight client so that I can checkout and checkin code. I do not want the whole subversion server.

Google search gave me [this link](https://subversion.apache.org/packages.html) . I followed the link to [this site](http://www.perzl.org/aix/index.php?n=Main.Subversion) . It lists rpms for subversion and their various dependencies ,  no where does it mention anything about the client.

Comment: Generally you get a server with the client. `svn` is probably the most light weight and will be the best option. Check the `configure` file to see if you can disable making the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link that you gave, also contained a link to the [AIX Specific Page](http://www.perzl.org/aix/index.php?n=Main.Subversion), which contains the rpm's and their needed dependencies.  Seeing as we both ended up on the same page, you are in the right place, but unfortunately, as SailorCire stated in his comment, it looks like the client comes bundled with the server.